# Importing p5 package into a React functional component?

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I'm trying to integrate [p5.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p5) into my React app.

There is an example showing how to do so here: https://dev.to/christiankastner/integrating-p5-js-with-react-i0d

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
  }

  Sketch = (p) => {

     p.setup = () => {
     ...
     }

     p.draw = () => {
     ...
     }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myP5 = new p5(this.Sketch, this.myRef.current)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef}>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But the example given is a Class component.

How can convert the above example into a functional component?

I tried the following:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import p5 from "p5";

const App = () => {
  const processingRef = useRef();

  const Sketch = p => {
    p.setup = () => {};

    p.draw = () => {};
  };

  const newp5 = new p5(Sketch, processingRef);

  return <div ref={processingRef} />;
};

export default App;
```

but i was thrown the error on line `const newp5 = new p5(Sketch, processingRef)`:

```
this._userNode.appendChild is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import p5 from "p5";

const App = () => {
  const processingRef = useRef();
  const Sketch = p => {
    p.setup = () => {};

    p.draw = () => {};
     };
   useEffect(() => {
    const newp5 = new p5(Sketch, processingRef.current);
    }, [])

  return <div ref={processingRef} />;
};

export default App;
```

> Passing no dependency in the *useEffect* hook makes it run once just like the *componentDidMount* Live Cycle Method

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the ref to be set first:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import p5 from "p5";

const App = () => {
  const setProcessingRef = (element) => {
    if (element) {
      const Sketch = (p) => {
        p.setup = () => {};

        p.draw = () => {};
      };

      const newp5 = new p5(Sketch, processingRef);
    }
  };

  return <div ref={setProcessingRef} />;
};

export default App;
```